# How to write Jasmine test for $timeout functions

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write a jasmine karma test for following code.

However I am able to get the unit test done for the $timeout function.

```
function onDataChange(e) {

        $timeout(function () {
            if ($scope.hasAccess) {
                //Do Something
            }
        });
    }
```

The unit test call to onDataChange with Param able get inside the function but not timeout.

Comment: You likely need to create a mock of `$timeout` in your unit test and resolve the promise in order to hit that `if ` statement.